# Real Analysis of Subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Are there any errors, mistakes, or deficiencies in this proposed proof?

PROPOSITION 51: If $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$, then $n_k≥k$ for every $k∈N$.

PROOF: Suppose that $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$. By definition, $\{n_k\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. Consequently, n_1 is a natural number. Therefore, because every natural number is greater than or equal to 1, $n_1 ≥ 1$ for $k = 1$. Thus, condition I of the PMI is satisfied. Let $n_p ≥ p$ for some $p∈N$. By definition of a strictly increasing sequence, ($n_p < n_{p+1}$ for every $p∈N$). Therefore, $n_{p+1} > p$ for some $p∈N$. Consequently, $n_{p+1} - p > 0$
Now both $n_{p+1}$ and p, as natural numbers, are positive integers. Therefore, by definition of integer subtraction and addition, $n_{p+1} - p > 0$ is an integer. Since $n_{p+1} - p$ is a positive integer, $(n_{p+1} - p)∈N$ has been proven for some $p∈N$. Again, because every natural number is greater than or equal to 1, $n_{p+1} - p≥ 1$ for some $p∈N$. Consequently, $n_{p+1} ≥ p + 1$ for some $(p + 1)∈N$.
Therefore, conditition II of PMI is satisfied. By the principle of mathematical induction, $n_k≥k$ has been proven for every $k∈N$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. When you write "$n_1 \ge 1$ for $k=1$ that's a bit redundant, since you're not using $k$ there. You could rephrase that as "$n_k = n_1 \ge 1$ for $k=1$" maybe. I'm also a bit confused why you switch between $p$ and $k$ when one would be fine.

Comment: I think because n_1≥1 for k=1 indicates that condition I of PMI is satisfied for n_k≥k. I also introduce p for the induction hypothesis that n_p≥p for some natural number p.

Comment: Quite, I understand. It's just some style feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors, no  mistakes and no deficiencies in your proof.